# How to manage the model of a really big form in Vue?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I'm currently writing a really big multipage form (about 60 fields). On the last page, the user will see a resume, so he can check all data before sending.

It's all managed in one single page (with 'page' slides), so I need to auto-populate the resume based on user inputs. I'm doing it with Vue, something like this:

```
<input name="contact[name]" v-model="name" id="name" type="text" value="" />
```

...later in resume:

```
<li><b>Name:</b> {{ name }}</li>
```

...And Vue:

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    name:''
  }
});
```

Ok, all fine. But I've got about 60 fields, and I should put them all into the `data` property of the Vue obj. Quite tedious.

Since I'm new to Vue, maybe I'm doing it the wrong way. If so, can please someone point me to the right direction?

I know I shoud ask the Vue forum, but they're really slow in answering questions..

Comment: I think you're probably going about it the right way. It's quite tedious sadly. You could also create an array of objects for those inputs (grouped if necessary) and then generate the inputs via a `v-for`, so that if you need to add/remove, you only have to do it in a single place. You could also add input types, validation params etc.

Comment: you can put it all in 1 object: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/9y01w4nq/1/ but this also limits the control you have on each value. For e.g. you can't `watch` a specific form value because it doesn't exist until the user input something

Comment: @JacobGoh but if you do it this way... https://jsfiddle.net/b97pnwyo/ you have the control that you may need. You can also add further parameters, such as regex strings etc.

Comment: @Beau yes. Defining all the form data upfront is still the best practice. I was just offering the OP an alternative

Comment: I'll try both routes I think, not sure what's the best, but the 1 obj way it's quite interesting.

Comment: In the end, I went for the @JacobGoh route :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I simplyfied it (following @JacobGoh's suggestion) was to use empty objects. This worked quite well for my specific needs. Also, as you can see, when you need to use watchers or to initialize a property (for example for select fields it's in general needed), you can just explicit only those related properties.
I ended up with about 20 props instead of the 60-70 being in fact processed.

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  el: '#form'
  ,data:{
    form:{
      contact:{}
      ,compiler:{}
      ,project:{}
      ,current_tools:{}
      ,screw:{
        type: "Flat"
        ,drive_shape: "Phillips"
        ,drive_type: 1
        ,has_mobile_washer: 'no'
        ,material: 'Iron'
        ,finish: 'Oil'
      }
      ,tightening:{}
      ,cicle:{}
      // [and so on...]
    }
  }// data
});
```